# Android Permission for scrolling on every app

Tags: android

I'm trying to develop an app which will let you, using Muse (www.choosemuse.com), to scroll on every app on the phone.

Is there a way to request global scrolling permissions? I can't find anything on the internet.

Comment: You can see if the accessibility framework offers scrolling, but I am not aware that it does. And, outside of that, you would be limited to rooted devices or your own custom ROM. Ordinary apps cannot inject input events into other apps.

Comment: @CommonsWare so basically, it can't be done?

Comment: Again, see if the accessibility framework offers something. That's the only thing available to somewhat-normal Android apps for affecting the UI of other apps.

Comment: @CommonsWare nope, i can't find anything in the Android documentation. So, i guess it's not possible. Thanks anyway. :)